# Sticky select with data from MySQL in PHP genereated form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a sticky `select` form, which gets the data for the `options` from MySQL. The form should display "Select Type" if no form was submitted (this works). Then I tried to make it sticky. My idea was to compare the `$_POST['type']` with the data from MySQL and if its the same it should echo selected.

The `$_POST['type']` was working perfectly when I tried to echo it, also the options from the MySQL DB are working.

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but I'm missing something. Any ideas?

```
<select type="text" name="type" id="type" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="" disabled <?php if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo "selected";} ?> >Select type</option>
                                <?php
                                    $result = mysql_query("select * from type");

                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                                    {
                                        $type[] = $row;
                                    }

                                    $count = count($type);

                                    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                                        {
                                            $selected = $_POST['type'];
                                            echo "<option";

                                            if($selected === $type[$i] ){
                                            echo "selected";
                                            }

                                            echo ">";
                                            echo $type[$i]['type'];
                                            echo '</option>';
                                        }
                                ?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sticky"?

Comment: It should remember what was selected from the user. For example: after I selected it and I forgot the date and submitted the form, the selected one should stay there, so the user doesn't have to select it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `echo "selected";` to `echo " selected ";`

It will currently echo `<optionselected>` on selected option which is malformed.

Comment: Thank you. I just corrected it, but nothing is displayed in the HTML sourcecode.